# Show $\mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}$ is dense and open in $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: calculus, general-topology

I was trying to prove the statement that 
$$\mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\} \text{ is dense and open in $\mathbb{R}$}$$ 
Could someone help to read my proof and give me some feedbacks/corrections.

Here is my try:

OPENNESS: To show $\mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\} \text{ is open in $\mathbb{R}$}$

Take any point $x \in \mathbb{R}\setminus \{0\}$, need to show there exists a neighborhood $\mathcal{B}{(x, \delta)}$ such that $\mathcal{B}{(x, \delta)} \subset \mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}$. Thus, let $\delta >0$ and an arbitrary point $y := x + \delta/2$ with $\delta >0$. Then observe that 
$$|x-y| = |x - (x + \delta/2)| < \delta$$ Thus, $y \in \mathcal{B}{(x, \delta)}$ and thus $y \in \mathbb{R}$. It implies $ \mathcal{B}{(x, \delta)} \subset \mathbb{R}$. Hence, $\mathbb{R}\setminus \{0\}$ is open.

DENSITY:

To show $\mathbb{R}\setminus \{0\}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$; it is obvious to see the set is dense in $\mathbb{R}$ except at one point $0$. So we just only need to check the density at that point $x =0$. Thus, we show the point $0$ is a limit point of the set $\mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}$. Let $\mathcal{B}(0,\delta)$ be any neighborhood of $0$, then take a point $\delta/2 \neq 0$ with any $\delta >0$. Then we can see that
$$
|\delta/2 -0 | < \delta
$$ so that $\delta/2 \in \mathcal{B}(0, \delta)$ and the point $\delta/2 >0$ which is contained in $\mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}$.

Comment: In other words, you're trying to show that $\{0\}$ is closed in $\mathbb R$ and does not contain an interval?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the proof that the set is open, it won't do to just say "let $\delta>0$".  If that worked, then the statement you're trying to prove would be true of ALL $\delta>0$, and clearly it's not.  Rather you need to show that THERE EXISTS $\delta>0$ for which the statement holds.  Find the appropriate value of $\delta>0$.  That's quite easy.

Comment: Thank you very much!! I got it.

Answer (score 3):

Your density argument is fine, albeit a little bit verbose (you really just need to present a sequence in $\mathbb{R} \setminus \{ 0 \}$ which converges to $0$).

Your openness argument is invalid: the $\delta$ that will work will depend on $x$. Specifically, you need $\delta \leq |x|$, so that the interval you're producing does not contain $0$.